# Need a faster method of dynamically loading start pages with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I have a PhoneGap 3 application for Android in which the initial screen that appears for a user could be one of two screens. The first is a simple login screen that allows them to access the main menu of my app. The second is a page that allows them to either take a survey immediately, or delay taking a survey for an amount of time. The only way to reach the second page is through clicking a notification which pops up in the application throughout a day.

Right now the login screen appears upon opening the application because the login page is the first chunk of html code within the body:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">

    <!-- login page -->
    <div id="login" data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header" id="login-header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

            <form id="form-login">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="login-password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="login-password" id="login-password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="password-field"/>
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="login-button" data-role="button" onclick="checkLogin()">Login</a>
            </form>
        </div>   

        <div data-role="footer" id="login-footer" data-theme="a">
            <h4 id="login-footer-header">UIC &amp; EVL</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Upon a user putting the application on pause, by hitting the home button for example, I have an onpause event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", userHasGoneIdle , false);
```

make a call to this function:

```
function userHasGoneIdle(){
    writingToRandomPromptInt = false;
    $("#login-password").val('');

    $.mobile.navigate('#login');

    resetSurveyWidgets();

    console.log('userHasGoneIdle');
}
```

So that the next time the user resumes the applciaiton, the login screen will load.

In order to load the second possible screen which allows a user to delay notifications, I use a similar $.mobile.navigate() function call to move to the page with the delay options. I call this function within an event listener 'onclick' of the local notification plugin I am using:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.onclick = function(id, state, json){
    $.mobile.navigate('#delay');
    console.log('\n clicking notification #' + id);
    ...
}
```

Here is the html for my delay page:

```
<!-- DELAY PAGE -->
<div data-role="page" id="delay">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="h">
        <h1 align="center">Delay Notification</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="delaycontent"></div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="delayNotification()" class="ui-disabled">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#login" class="ui-disabled">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The delay page will eventually load once a user clicks on a notification, but only after 1 - 3 seconds of being on the login page first. In that amount of time, a user can log in to the main menu only to be eventually taken back to the delay screen... I need a quicker method of loading the delay screen upon a user tapping a notification, so that users won't be presented the login screen at all.

I have looked at other threads in SO with regard to the slow nature of $.mobile.navigate, but I feel like my issue is different as I need to dynamically load one page or another, depending on the method of the user resuming the application.

Thanks for any help!